# Selecting two columns from different tables in relation MS SQLSERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, t-sql

I am moving from using Hibernate to SQL queries and this problem is rather difficult with my background in SQL:

I have the following table and the fields I am interesting in receiving:

::PROFILE_TABLE FIELDS::

ACCOUNT_FK   > OWNER_FK

RECEIVER_FK  > ACCOUNT_FK  > _ OWNER_FK

I need to get the OWNER in the ACCOUNT table for each record in this profile table, I can't think of a way of doing this without a huge sql query which I can't even think of right now.  The profile table has an account field and a receiver field which also contains an account field in the table.

Obviously in Hibernate and java classes I can just use

Profile.Account.Owner is in array Or Profile.Receiver.Account.Owner is in array to check if any of these two owners for each profile is present.

Anyone have ideas?

Select the owner from the account table where account.id = profile.account_fk and then union this for the multiple joins I need for the receiver?

Comment: Show sample table data and expected result..

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more detail about desired results and actual DDL:

Just using joins to find `@owner_id` for either account.

```
select
  p.*
from profile_table p
  inner join account a on p.account_id = a.account_id
  inner join receiver r on p.receiver_id = receiver_id
  inner join account ra on r.account_id = ra.account_id
where @owner_id in (a.owner_id,ra.owner_id)
```

or with `union all`

```
select
  p.*
from profile_table p
  inner join account a on p.account_id = a.account_id
where @owner_id = a.owner_id    
union all
select
  p.*
from profile_table p
  inner join receiver r on p.receiver_id = receiver_id
  inner join account ra on r.account_id = ra.account_id
where @owner_id = ra.owner_id
```

If you have to check by some other column in `owner` that is not the foreign key:

```
select
  p.*
  , o.name 
  , ro.name as receiver_name
from profile_table p
  inner join account a on p.account_id = a.account_id
  inner join owner o on a.owner_id = o.owner_id
  inner join receiver r on p.receiver_id = receiver_id
  inner join account ra on r.account_id = ra.account_id
  inner join owner ro on ra.owner_id = ro.owner_id
where @somecol in (o.somecol, ro.somecol)
```

Comment: Hi @SqlZim,

I attempted to use your code but not understanding the use of the variable as it's value is never initialized so I received 0 results.

The desired results would be the list of IDs for the Owner which I can then join to a list to check if it is present; I guess you could also do this in the same Query, just another table containing owners (like a blacklist).

The tables are as follows:

#PROFILE ; [ACCOUNT_FK, RECEIVER_FK]

#RECEIVER ; [ACCOUNT_FK]

#ACCOUNT ; [OWNER_FK]